# VS code как настроить форматирование .ino файлов

Tags: arduino, visual-studio-code

Поставил плагин от майкрософ для разработки arduino в Visual studio code но при автоформатировании при нажатии `ctrl+shift+i` редактор переносит фигурную скобку на следующую строку, например при объявлении процедуры и не только:

```
void setup
{
  ...
}
```

а хотелось бы так:

```
void setup {
  ...
}
```

Как исправить?

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings

Comment: на каком языке пишете?

Comment: Wiring https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiring_(development_platform), но думается мне что VSC распознает его как C но тут я не уверен, тк установлен плагин от майкрософт который мог что то донастроить по этому поводу.

Comment: Похоже, что в настройках студии перенос фигурной скобки можно настроить только для TypeScript, например - *"typescript.format.placeOpenBraceOnNewLineForFunctions": false*

Comment: А файл с каким расширением сохраняете?

Comment: @Anatol указано в вопросе *.ino

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Установите clang-format.

Поставьте плагин VSCode Clang-format.

В settings.json укажите настройку

```
...
"clang-format.executable": "clang-format", // или путь до clang-format
...
```

В корневой папке проекта создайте файл .clang-format например с содежимым:

```
BraceWrapping:
  AfterClass:      true
  AfterControlStatement: true
  AfterEnum:       true/false
  AfterFunction:   true
  AfterNamespace:  true/false
  AfterObjCDeclaration: true/false
  AfterStruct:     true/false
  AfterUnion:      true/false
  BeforeCatch:     true/false
  BeforeElse:      true/false
  IndentBraces:    true/false
BreakBeforeBraces: Custom
```

Готово!

Документация clang-format: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html

Источник: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29477654/how-to-make-clang-format-add-new-line-before-opening-brace-of-a-function

Интерактивное создание конфигурации .clang-format: https://clangformat.com/

Comment: как вариант. Другого решения так я и не нашел. Спасибо.